# Outlook - Schedule a 1 week break in fortnightly recurring meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, appointments

I have a timetable that runs on a bi-weekly repeating pattern. I have all these appointments scheduled into my Outlook calendar with meeting notes / PowerPoints etc added to the appointments.

Now we need to move the entire schedule forwards 1 week so it happens on the alternating week in the fortnight.

Is there a way to do this en-masse without losing my earlier scheduled meetings and information? If I change the start date to shift the recurrence it deletes earlier appointments.

Answer (score 2):

According to [This page on Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cancel-all-future-meetings-in-a-series-9eaeee8c-bfe3-46a0-a092-9a2707f3b133), you can cancel all future meetings in a series as follows:

1. Go into your calendar.
2. Select (double-click) any meeting in the series
3. Click **The Entire Series** then **OK**
4. Click **Recurrence**
5. Under **Range of Occurrence**, click **End by** and enter a date prior to the next meeting in the series

The rest of what happens is administrative, e.g., a warning about specific changed meetings, notificiations, et cetera - see the linked page.

After you cancel the future meetings, you can obviously set up a new series of meetings on the alternate weeks.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do the Set up a new series of meetings bit. I wanted to simply insert a break and have them all still exist

Comment: @JoeTaylor - Sadly, that doesn't appear to be possible. You can change the options for all meetings in a series, or for one, but not, apparently, for all future - I tried the procedure at [this page at NMU](https://it.nmu.edu/docs/change-meeting-outlook), but it retroactively changed past meetings - which is stupid design... (but we are talking about Microsoft...)

Comment: looks like its a load of manual work for me then. It's occurred due to a half term so with the increasing push for teams in education hopefully it's a feature that'll be requested more and more

Comment: It shouldn't be a lot of manual work; just the cancel and the create new series. Since the new series will be a recurrent series, presumably on the same day/time every second week, you should be able to set it up in one quick operation.

Comment: It seems that Jeff's suggestion is better option.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel one meeting in a series in Outlook :

- Go to the Calendar view.
- Select and double click the occurrence meeting which you want to cancel
- In the "Open Recurring Item" dialog box, check "Open this occurrence box"
  (or "Just this one") and click OK
- In the "Meeting Occurrence" window, click "Cancel Meeting"
- In the "Confirm Delete" dialog, check "Delete this occurrence",
  and click OK.
- Alternatively, if available in your Outlook, just select the meeting
  and click *Cancel Meeting > Cancel Occurrence*
- Click "Send Cancellation" to send the message to the participants.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to cancel one meeting in a series in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1659-outlook-cancel-one-meeting-in-a-series.html)

Comment: It sounds like he actually wants to cancel _all_ of the future meetings on this schedule, and then set up a new schedule for these meeting that now will occur on the weeks that were previously idle.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Cancelling a series seems too simple to warrant a post here ...

Comment: Except that if you just cancel the series, it'll delete the previous (past) meetings from the calendar - which he doesn't want. Thus my answer and the link therein.

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for, I want to shift the whole set of weekly meetings 1 week forwards. Cancelling a single occurrence wouldn't do what I need sorry. Thanks though